# Xamarin: "Frame not in module" - VS 2013&2015

Tags: debugging, xamarin

I am very disappointed from the XAMARIN Support!

So, I will start from the beginning...

Everything was OK in the last few months, until I did an update to the last version of xamarin (4.0.3.214) -  the result is that I can't Debug now. I get the following message

> "Frame not in module"

I sent an e-mail to Xamarin support - and received an answer after about 24 hours. Their reply was:

> "Could you please go to Debug and find the Exceptions window, then
>   pick "Restore the List to the Default Settings"
>   (http://screencast.com/t/OrBejA25)"

This did not work.

I have tried many options:

1. Uninstall Vs 2013 and Xamarin, then install VS 2015 with Xamarin, on my pc & my Laptop - Same Problem.
2. Enable / Disable "Just My Code" - Same Problem
3. "Use Fast Deployment (Check/UnCheck) - Same Problem.
4. Create New Project - Same Problem.

I'm Stuck now on middle of project and Can't do nothing!

Comment: Android or iOS? Visual Studio I assume? Is this on-device debugging or using a simulator? If a simulator, which one? Please share your project build settings - particularly your build configuration and linker settings.

Comment: hi, Android Project, Visual studio 2013 & 2015, debugging on real device, even i create new project the problem is appear.... Linker setting is: none

Comment: Have you altered any of the projects properties (I assume not, since you are saying that it happens with new projects too)? Also, does it work when debugging in a simulator?

Comment: yes, same problem on simulator.

Comment: Update:

after i was installed version: 3.11.1594.0 the debugger start working FINALLY!!!.

i hope that i will not against with any ERRORS because i downgrade to this version.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Yosi,

I am also facing same problem. Is there any success in this? I have tried solutions provided by experts in this link but didn't work for me.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27308/debugger-doesnt-work-frame-not-in-module

Comment: i am also stuck in same problem but did not get solution yet...

Comment: I am also stuck with this for months now. Reaaaally frustrating. I already tried so much