# Frame not in module - Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin 2.3.247

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I've been getting the "Frame not in module" error while trying to debug my mobile app ever since I've installed VS 2015 with Xamarin. I'm taking over a project from a another team member, his development environment works fine and he is able to debug. We've compared NuGet packages and we're both using the same versions. This error happens every time I try and debug through code/functions which reference Xamarin Forms.

I've tried various various workarounds and theories which I've found online, including uninstalling VS Studio/Xamarin and reinstalling the whole lot. I've tried solutions suggested here:

- [Error "Frame not in module." in Xamarin.Forms - Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917142/error-frame-not-in-module-in-xamarin-forms-android-project) and
- [Xamarin Android Exception causes "Frame not in module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179513/xamarin-android-exception-causes-frame-not-in-module) and
- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90566/debugger-doesnt-work-frame-not-in-module and
- [Xamarin: "Frame not in module" - VS 2013&2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589482/xamarin-frame-not-in-module-vs-20132015).

Has there been an updated solution to this issue recently? Does anybody have other workarounds that have worked for them?

Answer (score 0):

Gave up trying to fix this issue and decided to upgrade to Visual Studio 2017. After migrating the project and updating the NuGet packages I can debug and step through the code successfully.